# Comparing datetime object to 8601 strings gives wrong result, why is it allowed?

Tags: python, datetime, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Maybe I am missing something obvious, but it looks like date comparing is off here:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

import pandas as pd
import datetime

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

action_pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({"customerId": ["Cat", "Hat", "Bat"],
                                 "timeStamp": ["2016-06-29T09:11:26Z",
                                               "2016-07-30T09:11:26Z",
                                               "2016-06-29T23:11:26Z"]})

action_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(action_pandas_df)
action_df.show()

cut_off = datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 29, 15)

print "\033[0;34m{}\033[0m".format(cut_off.strftime(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))

new_df = action_df.filter(action_df.timeStamp > cut_off)
new_df.show()
```

I get:

```
+----------+--------------------+
|customerId|           timeStamp|
+----------+--------------------+
|       Cat|2016-06-29T09:11:26Z|
|       Hat|2016-07-30T09:11:26Z|
|       Bat|2016-06-29T23:11:26Z|
+----------+--------------------+
```

What I don't understand is why date on Cat `2016-06-29T09:11:26Z` is considered greater then `cut_off` which is: `2016-06-29T15:00:00Z`.

I know that I can use `cut_off.strftime(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')` instead of `cutoff` and I would get the expected result.

As a side note:

For larger `cut_off` date, I get expected result:

```
cut_off = datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 10, 15)
```

My code works as expected.

Why is comparing `datatime` object to 8601 strings is allowed?

What am I missing?

Edit:

I am using Spark 1.5

Edit 2:

Spark 1.6.1 gives the same behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't compare dates. Since types don't match and column is a string query is casted to string as well. String representation of `cut_off` in SQL is `2016-06-29 15:00:00`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

cut_off = datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 29, 15)

action_df.select(lit(cut_off).cast("string")).limit(1).show()
## +--------------------------------+
## |cast(1467205200000000 as string)|
## +--------------------------------+
## |             2016-06-29 15:00:00|
## +--------------------------------+
```

and when you compare strings using lexicographical order and `'T'` > `' '`. You can either compare with formatted string:

```
cut_off_str = cut_off.strftime(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

action_df.where(action_df.timeStamp > cut_off_str).show()
## +----------+--------------------+
## |customerId|           timeStamp|
## +----------+--------------------+
## |       Hat|2016-07-30T09:11:26Z|
## |       Bat|2016-06-29T23:11:26Z|
## +----------+--------------------+
```

or parse column first:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp

timestamp_parsed = (unix_timestamp(action_df.timeStamp, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'kk:mm:ss")
    .cast("double")      # Required only for Spark 1.5
    .cast("timestamp"))

action_df.where(timestamp_parsed > cut_off).show()
## +----------+--------------------+
## |customerId|           timeStamp|
## +----------+--------------------+
## |       Hat|2016-07-30T09:11:26Z|
## |       Bat|2016-06-29T23:11:26Z|
## +----------+--------------------+
```